# ExtJS mvc: where to keep the active tab data

Tags: extjs, model-view-controller, extjs4

I'm using ExtJS with the MVC pattern. My app has, among other things, a tab area in which multiple instances of a data are shown. Each tab has its own storage, but they share the same controller instance, since they are exactly the same view. This is allowed by the fact the Controller is completely stateless. But in the controller there is plenty of code looking for "the active tab", since controller need somehow to know on which view is acting in order to recover some data from the store to properly work. Where is the place to maintain the current active tab? I have another controller, call it main, who orchestrate tab creations, but I cant keep there since this violates the state requirement for the controller. Any idea/suggestion?

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Are these tabs actual `Ext.tab.Tab` classes/are you extending it?  If so, are they contained in an `Ext.tab.Panel`?  If those assumptions are true, why not just use [getActiveTab](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-method-getActiveTab)?

Comment: Assumption are correct. I'm asking if getting the active tab in order to have the current data is conform to MVC

Comment: Ah, ok.  Now I understand your question.